# Call UNIX commands (nice, renice) in Python

Tags: python, linux, unix

I'm making a Python program to assign new values to processes and dynamically monitor them:

```
import os
import subprocess
#!/usr/bin/env python
print "hello world"
os.system("ps lx")
print "Enter PID"
pid = raw_input()
print "Entered PID",pid
print "Enter new priority"
new = raw_input()
print "Entered new priority is"new
os.system("sudo renice new pid")
```

I don't know how to call `nice` and `renice` with arguments in Python.

Comment: We don't do *"urgent"*, this isn't a helpdesk; see http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/6506/248731

Comment: @jonrsharpe: never know about it sorry. Just added urgent to get quick attention.

Answer (score 2):

Use `subprocess`:

```
from subprocess import Popen,PIPE

p = Popen(["sudo","-S", "renice",new , pid], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
p.stdin.write("password\n")
```

You can use also `subprocess.check_call`:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE,check_call

check_call(["ps", "lx"])
pid = raw_input("Enter PID")
print "Entered PID",pid
new = raw_input("Enter new priority")
print "Entered new priority is",new

p = Popen(["sudo","-S", "renice", new, pid], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
p.stdin.write("pc160780\n")
out, err = p.communicate()

print(out if out else err)
```

Comment: OP  imported subprocess but never used heeeee

Comment: Paradic include `from subprocess import Popen` else will get importError :)

Comment: @Hackaholic, indeed. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks @PadraicCunningham for help. Is question is so dumb that it get 3 negative votes? ;(

Comment: @AkshayBirajdar perhaps *"badly written"* would be more accurate than *"dumb"*.

Comment: @AkshayBirajdar, no prob.